# Use MPI with Rcpp and RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, mpi, openmp, rcpp, armadillo

I am trying to use MPI within an Rcpp/RcppArmadillo code. I read about how to use MPI in R or in general using C. However, I can't seem to find any good documentation about how to use it within the Rcpp/RcppArmadillo code. I am pasting below a test case just as an example. I would like to use MPI on the for loop inside the function named mainFunction(). Would appreciate any help.

We already have openmpi installed in the cluster but not sure how to implement it in here.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <omp.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]


using namespace std;
using namespace arma;


mat someFunction(mat &A,mat &B){

  mat C(A.n_rows,A.n_cols);
  unsigned int n = A.n_rows * A.n_cols;

#pragma omp parallel for 
  for(unsigned int i=0; i< n; i++){
     C[i] = exp(A[i])/3 + pow(A[i],-.5) + B[i];
  } 

  return C;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
cube mainFunction(cube &A, cube &B){

  unsigned int nsl = A.n_slices;
  cube C(A.n_rows,A.n_cols,nsl);


  for(unsigned int i=0; i< nsl; i++){
    C.slice(i) = someFunction(A.slice(i),B.slice(i));
  }

  return C;
}
```

Comment: Generally, MPI is handled in the _R_ session and not in _C++_ via `Rmpi` package. Though, you can also do it in _C++_ by using `mpi.h` header with the appropriate initialization statements. If your cluster supports Job Arrays, I would consider doing it that way instead of rewriting the code to support MPI.

Comment: You could also implement the MPI portion using `future` instead of `Rmpi`, c.f. https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/blob/master/tests/mpi.R

Comment: @coatless: Thank you so much for the future link and the comments. In general, I am aware of the fact that I could use the MPI portion using Rmpi or similar. However, because of the overhead and other complexities, I like to implement it in C++. I was looking at mpi.h and using appropriate initialization statements. But how do I compile the Rcpp function using mpic++ (how to specify these in makevars)? Also, will I be able to submit the job using Rscript? A reproducible example or any documentation with Rcpp would be extremely helpful.

Comment: "Generally, MPI is handled in the R session and not in C++ via Rmpi package" -- because it is much easier that way.  You can of course do everything lower level too.  It all depends.  Also see RcppParallel which has been combined fruitfully with other Rcpp* packages.

Comment: You could also consider these [using R embedded via RInside with MPI](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside/tree/master/inst/examples/mpi) examples.

Comment: Thanks for the two awesome packages (RcppParallel & RInside) Dirk! I have used RcppParallel before as well. However, given the problem's complexity and data heaviness, I would prefer to use mpi within Rcpp first and deploy it in our cluster using multiple nodes. If this fails then I would rewrite the c++ functions to use Rmpi/future/RInside. I need to figure out how to put the flags properly and a few other things before I use mpi.h.

Comment: @Ghosh May I know how you overcome this hurdle? It would be appreciated if you could share your experience.

Comment: It is certainly possible as you can see in the RInside package but I had to move on to different work. I would definitely like to come back to it at some point.